# Per-iteration variable in Nim?

Tags: for-loop, lambda, pass-by-reference, anonymous-function, nim-lang

```
var functions: seq[proc(): int] = @[]
functions.add(proc(): int = 233)
for i in 1 .. 5:
  functions.add(proc(): int = i)

for i in 1 .. 5:
  echo functions[i]()
```

output

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Seems like Nim stores free variable `i` in these anonymous functions by reference instead of values just like Python, Ruby and Groovy. How can I get its value instead of reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the capture macro, see [the docs in `std/sugar`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html#capture.m,varargs%5Btyped%5D,untyped)

```
import std/sugar
var functions: seq[proc(): int] = @[]
for i in 1 .. 5:
  capture i:
    functions.add(proc(): int = i)

for fn in functions:
  echo fn()
```

There's also [captureScope in system](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#closureScope.t%2Cuntyped) (system module is always implicitly imported), but the docs suggest using `capture` from `std/sugar`.